# sum of different files in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a List

```
paths = ['1.xlsx', '2.xlsx', '3.xlsx', '4.xlsx', '5.xlsx', '6.xlsx', '7.xlsx', '8.xlsx', '9.xlsx']
```

that has names of file

and a function `sum_invoice(path)`   it returns sum or total in the specified file

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelFile
def sum_invoice(path):
    xl = ExcelFile(path)
    for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
        df = xl.parse(sheet)
        xy=df['INVOICE']
        nn=pd.to_numeric(xy, 'coerce')
        nn = nn.reset_index(drop=True)
        nn.fillna(0)
        total=nn.loc[nn.last_valid_index()]
        return total
#create list of files named paths
paths =[]
for path in glob.iglob('*.xlsx'):
    paths.append(path)
    print(path)


sum_all = sum(sum_invoice(path) for paths in paths)
print sum_all
```

how to iterate over these file with the function  and also sum the total returned from all files.

Comment: So, is this a Python 2 or a Python 3 specific question?

Comment: python  2.7 @Juanpa.arrivillage

Comment: How are the files structures?

Comment: Name your function something other than `sum`  Then you can do `sum(your_function(path) for path in paths)`.  `sum` is the name of a built in python function, but you can't use it if you're using the name for something else

Comment: Paths is of type List that has all the files name in that same directory and the function sun(path) this argument needs to take each file in the list and returns a float that needs to be stored and added with the rest of the other xlsx files to have the final output that is sum of returned values from the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that like below, but you need first to rename your `sum` function to something like `my_sum` (because `sum()` is a built-in function that you should not override):

```
sum_all = sum(my_sum(path) for path in paths)
```

**Edit:**

Now, that your custom sum function is renamed to `sum_invoice`, you can use:

```
sum_all = sum(sum_invoice(path) for path in paths)
```

The above line uses generator expression, for more details about this topic, you can check this [PEP 289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). A simple solution with for loop looks as follows:

```
sum_all = 0

for path in paths:
    s = sum_invoice(path)
    sum_all += s
```

Comment: Is `sum` in this context the built-in `sum` or their function `sum(path)`?

Comment: This will not work for OP because builtin sum is shadowed

Comment: That's not a list comprehension. That is a generator expression.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, the second one is of course the OP's sum function

Comment: The sum_invoice is a function i made it gets a specific float value from each excel file  and the excel file are named in paths

Comment: @VSCompiler that's fine, so you can use `sum_invoice` where I use `my_sum` above. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: i tried it it returns wrong sum amount and it prints ~$1.xlsx and ~$5.xlsx??

Comment: your `sum_invoice` function does not use `path` at all, you need to put `xl = ExcelFile(path)` inside `sum_invoice` and remove this line `path= '5.xlsx'`

Comment: updated but for the PATHS list it adds to files named "~$1.xlsx" and "~$5.xlsx" i am not sure why these are added  in the list although the folder dont have such file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129575/discussion-between-vs-compiler-and-ettanany).

Answer (score 3):

There is already a [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function in the standard library. You should rename your function to `sum_path()` or similar.

Then you can achieve what you want by using a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) with `sum()` as:

```
sum(sum_path(p) for p in paths)
```